# Dynamic Column Name change Based on Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

Any one could you please help me on  Dynamic Column Name change Based on Slicer Selection.

below is the senario.

Matrix visual

```
product Name     Year 
XXX 56
YYY 87
ZZZ 78
```

Slicer Selection

```
Year 
2016-17
2017-18
2018-19
2019-20
```

when i select year 2017-18 , column name on matrix should change dynamicaaly as  Year 2017-18 .

Comment: Check out Field Parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters

Comment: This question is not clear and will lead to discussions afterwards.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, indeed I use field parameters but is there a way to rename dynamically field name based on selectedvalue of the periode?